# Do I need a webserver inside of elasticbeanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to run a expressjs application inside of Elasticbeanstalk, but I don't want to have apache or nginx infront of it. I want just the ELB infront. Reading the tutorial it seems there is always a web server infront. Is this necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elastic beanstalk will give you a load balancer if you tell it to be a load balanced application, but the beanstalk configuration will give you a web server regardless from the container.

Comment: So if it is a nodejs expressjs application can I specify it to use expressjs instead of apache or nginx? If not, do the apache and nginx run on a new instance which I must pay for?

Comment: You arent able to change the web server for beanstalk unfortunately.

Comment: You technically can change it, I don't think this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly change it from Apache to Nginx if you want. You can't get rid of the web server all together though, as far as I know. I suppose you could launch a Docker application instead of a NodeJS application and then you would have more control over things like this. Having Nginx in front of a NodeJS application generally improves performance so I wouldn't get rid of it without good reason.

**EDIT:**

According to the documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-elastic-beanstalk-for-nodejs/):

> Choose Nginx or Apache as the reverse proxy to your Node.js
>   application. You can even choose to not use any proxy if your
>   application requires that the client establishes a direct connection.

Comment: Are these webservers a separate ec2 instance which I must may for?

Comment: No they run on the same server/EC2 instances as NodeJS

Comment: Thanks! That is all I need to know!